# Multiple attr jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to give the user an option so he can write `ID`s of wordpress categories that are going to be shown on an specific page.

The wordpress field is going to be named `the_field('categories_id')` so if he enters there IDs with comma separated like this `84, 95, 10`. Then all of this are shown.

I have made it work with only one `id`, for example if page `body.term-espectaculos` the show a `.filter li` with `data-filter=".filter-84"`.

This is working ok using this code:

```
if(jQuery('body').hasClass('term-espectaculos')){
    if(jQuery('.filters li').attr('data-filter=".filter-84"') !== undefined ){
        jQuery(this).fadeIn()
    }
}
```

The problem is that the user must be able to add multiple `ID`s so it's not going to be only one like in this example. How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to only fade in the list items that have a `data-filter` attribute that is in your comma-seperated list:

```
var values = '84, 95, 10',
    valArr = values.split(', ');
if(jQuery('body').hasClass('term-espectaculos')){
    jQuery('.filters li').filter(function(){
        var thisFilter = ($(this).attr('data-filter') || '').replace('.filter-','');
        return $.inArray(thisFilter, valArr) > -1;
    }).fadeIn();
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sodc2jnz/1/)

Note that this requires that your values in string form are split up by precisely a comma and a space. You may want to split on just a comma and then trim your array values:

```
var values = '84, 95, 10',
    valArr = $.map(values.split(','), function(v){ return $.trim(v); });
```

Comment: Yeah, you are understanding it right :) I'm trying with your code but I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

Comment: @dbada That is because of some `<li>` items with no `data-filter` attribute. Please see my update.

Answer (score 2):

add a json encoded array to your `data-filter` by `jQuery('.filters li').data('filter', jsonEncodedArray);`

EDIT: In php you can encode to a json array like this:

```
$array = array(84,95,10);
echo json_encode($array);
```

In javascript:

```
var array = [84,95,10];
var jsonEncodedArray = JSON.stringify(array);
```

Comment: I have never used this `jsonEncodedArray`. What would be the way to implement it?